# Java EE VS. Java SE programming

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, programming-languages

I know the difference between Java EE and Java SE. But my question, is there difference in the Java programming language for Java SE and Java EE?

Means I've learned Java and worked on Java SE but if I have to work on Java EE, do I need to learn Java for EE? Or is it the same?

Comment: As an aside, I've fixed the question up but Java isn't an acronym - so it's just Java, not JAVA.

Comment: [Java SE vs Java EE](https://github.com/ThreaT/Java-SE-vs-Java-EE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the language itself is the same - it's just a matter of the environment in which it's used, basically.

It's probably more important to be aware of the differences between different *versions* of Java (e.g. Java 7 and Java 8) in terms of language features - if you try to use a lambda expression in an environment that only supports Java 7, for example, you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can say that Java SE defines the basic concepts of Java which also remains the same in Java EE but there are many more things which comes under Java EE and you have to learn separately like JSF, JSP and Web services.

Answer (score 0):

Java EE is mainly used for the development of Web Application and as we know there are number of other things apart from only java lines are coming into picture for eg : session Management,Security of Transaction,Concurrent behavior of transaction,Work in distributed environment,persistence,locking,ratio to serve request per hit of URL many more ...... and for that Using Java EE we can achieve that as having various different opensource technologies are available

Spring Framework,
EJB 
Struts
Hibernate(ORM framework)
iBaties
JSF 
jsp+Servlet
:
:
:
Many other technologies can be helpful to develop web application.